# Doesn't build OBJ-C code in Qmake project

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt

> /Users/uuu/Projects/osx/Menu.mm:28:
>   error: attempting to use the forward class 'NSObject' as superclass
>   of 'MenuProvider' @interface MenuProvider : NSObject
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^

in code:

```
@interface MenuProvider : NSObject
- (void)share:(bool)force userData:(NSString*)data;
@end
```

Qt Creator (qt 5.3), clang-600.0.51, osx

Answer (score 1):

Add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` above that `@interface` definition.